# What is this M font?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I just found this M in my physics book. Do you know what font is used?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a special math Fraktur to me…

Comment: Looks like some `Fraktur ` font (but not the default `\mathfrak`).

Comment: Yeah, but wich one?

Comment: Because you want  *exactly* the same? It may be a commercial font.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At first glance I thought it was some Fraktur style, but a quick search on [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont) leads to the following result:

> [image: French Script]

As expected, this typeface (French Script) is commercial (maybe it is a built-in system font, but still, commercial nonetheless).

---

Here is an example using XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
\setmathfont{Frscript.ttf}[range=scr]

\begin{document}
Just for fun:
$\overrightarrow{\symscr{M}_O} \bigl( \overrightarrow{F} \bigr) = \overrightarrow{OM} \wedge \overrightarrow{F}$
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Excellent. Can you expain me the command `\symscr`? Does exists the boldsymbol of this fraktur M? Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano `\symscr` is a `unicode-math` package command. It roughly means “use script font but treat the letter as symbol, not as text”.

Comment: Thank you very much. There was before my +1